# Angular2 rc5: changing navigation in named outlet from another named outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my application in top level component I have 3 router outlets.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="r_popup"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="kyc"></router-outlet>
```

Within **r_popup** outlet I display a 'myaccount' component. At this moment my url looks as follows `http://localhost:4200/(r_popup:myaccount/account-details/summary)`. It works great.

Now, within myaccount I need to create a link that when clicked will change navigation for 'kyc' outlet. 
I've made it as follows `<a class="warning-label link-label" [routerLink]="[{outlets: {kyc: ['kyc']}}]">Verify Now</a>`

The problem is that router tries to  use "kyc" outlet within myaccount. This outlet of course doesn't exist.

- I'm getting this url:`http://localhost:4200/(r_popup:myaccount/(kyc:kyc))`
- But I need it to look like that: `http://localhost:4200/(r_popup:myaccount/account-details/summary//kyc:kyc)`

How can I accomplish this?